# sigsev error;can anyone look at the code and find out what is causing sigsev error

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

It simply takes the string as input and encode in the two steps-
index 1 and 2 are swapped,index 3 and 4 ,index 5 and 6...and so on.if the string is of odd length;then the last character remain as it is.After step1, letters are encoded accordingly- a to z,z to a,b to y..and so on

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char* encode(char* word,int N);
void swap(char* a,char* b);
int main()
{   
    int T,N;
    cin>>T;
    char word[100];
    while(T)
    {
        cin>>N;
        //char word[N];

        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
            cin>>word[i];

        cout<<encode(word,N)<<"\n";

        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
            word[i]=' ';   

        T--;
    }
    return 0;
}



char* encode(char* word,int N)
{
    int length;
    N%2==0?length=N:length=N-1;
    if(N%2!=0)
        word[N-1]=char(219-word[N-1]);

    for(int i=0;i<length;i=i+2)
    { 
        swap(word[i],word[i+1]);
        word[i]=char(219-word[i]);
        word[i+1]=char(219-word[i+1]);
    }

    return word;
}

void swap(char* a,char* b)
{
    char* temp;
    temp=b;
    b=a;
    a=temp;
}
```

Comment: Regarding `swap`, remember that assigning to a parameter has no effect on the object whose value you passed to the function; there is nothing special about pointers. As an added bonus, you're never using that function.

Comment: Initialise your variables - `char word[100] = {};` - so the string is properly terminated, make sure that `N` is never greater than 99, and declare `word` inside the loop so you don't need that "reset loop" (which is wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, replace:

```
using namespace std;
```

with:

```
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) why. Now you can see your code does not compile, because there is no `swap` function taking two chars. You have to change the line:

```
swap(word[i],word[i+1]);
```

into:

```
swap(&word[i],&word[i+1]);
```

Now you pass two adresses into the swap function, but it still does not do what you want. You have to change it into following:

```
char temp;
temp=*b;
*b=*a;
*a=temp;
```

Because you want to swap **values** instead of where the pointers point to.
Lastly, initialize your `word` array with `{}`:

```
char word[100]{};
```

As pointed by @molbdnilo in the comments so it does end printing after 100 characters.

Comment: I am still getting segmentation fault... i think there is some error in this particular part                                                                       for(int i=0;i<length;i=i+2)
 { 
     
  swap(&word[i],&word[i+1]);
  word[i]=char(219-word[i]);
  word[i+1]=char(219-word[i+1]);
 }

Comment: For what input? I cannot crash it on my side.

Comment: it is a part of codechef problem,for their input it is crashing...I dont know whats faulty!

Answer (score 1):

Your swap function doesn't work and cannot work. Also your array doesn't contain trailing zero, after that attempting to output string without trail zero may end badly..

`swap(word[i],word[i+1]);`

probably calls something else because your function isn't compatible with that call, `std::swap` because you're using `namespace std`. You didn't need to implement your own.